# Remove *No example questions yet. Add one below!* from closed proposals

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I was viewing [a closed proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62436/email-and-thank-you-note-etiquette) today and noticed that the

> No example questions yet. **Add one below**!

was still there.

[image]

This should be removed or changed because it is impossible to add an example question on a closed proposal and this might confuse new users.